# Can not view variable values in debugger after Swift 3 migration

Tags: ios, xcode

We have migrated our iOS project to Swift 3 and Xcode 8. Since then the debugger can not show any value of variables. If I try to print a variable:

```
p someVar
```

I get this error message. `SchemaManager.h` is a bridging header. (The actual project name has been replaced with yyy below):

```
warning: Swift error in module yyy.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'yyy' from AST context:
/Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/SchemaManager.h:10:9: note: while building module 'SQLiteMacOSX' imported from /Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/SchemaManager.h:10:
#import <sqlite3.h>
        ^

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:35:10: note: while building module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:35:
#include <stdarg.h>     /* Needed for the definition of va_list */
         ^

<module-includes>:33:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:33:
#import "util.h"
        ^

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/util.h:107:10: error: 'utmp.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#include <utmp.h>
         ^

/Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/SchemaManager.h:10:9: note: while building module 'SQLiteMacOSX' imported from /Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/SchemaManager.h:10:
#import <sqlite3.h>
        ^

<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
        ^

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:35:10: error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <stdarg.h>     /* Needed for the definition of va_list */
         ^

/Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/Bridging-Header.h:12:9: note: in file included from /Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/Bridging-Header.h:12:
#import "SchemaManager.h"
        ^

error: /Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/SchemaManager.h:10:9: error: could not build module 'SQLiteMacOSX'
#import <sqlite3.h>
        ^

error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/xxx/Documents/yyy/yyy/Common/Model/Bridging-Header.h'
```

The core error boils down to this:

```
error: 'utmp.h' file not found
```

I have read elsewhere that problems in bridging header can stop the debugger from showing variable values. But I am not sure how I go about fixing this particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Clean out your bridging header and make sure you have only what you need.

I was having the same problem, but with no output after the `failed to get module 'yyy' from AST context`.  I removed everything from my bridging header and added items back one-by-one to be sure I needed everything.

I found that adding `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` at the top was necessary (but originally missing) and found a few that I didn't need as I changed my project structure and forgot to remove some of the includes.  After all that, it started working.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have two header files imported from the bridging header. I need both. Commenting either of them causes compile problems.

Comment: I saw early success with this idea, but the problem comes back intermittently. I think the issue is elsewhere and changing pods changed enough to have it go away until I changed something else.  This is frustrating.

Comment: Ok.  After another ``pod update`` some more pods were converted to Swift 3 from Objective C, so after a clean and adding the appropriate import statements to the various swift files that use those pods, and then removing the from the pod file, the debugger is back!